# Whats the best way to get text from a .txt file to a vector<string>? C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mobile

I asked a question yesterday but i didn't manage to do anything. I am using visual studio with marmalade and im already studying c++ but i need to get things done here so i asking for i little help and patience of you guys.

I got a few responses like

```
std::ifstream inp("restrict_words.txt");
std::istream_iterator<std::string> inp_it(inp), inp_eof;
std::vector<std::string> words(inp_it, inp_eof);

// words now has ever whitespace separated string 
//  from the input file as a vector entry
for (auto s : words)
    std::cout << s << '\n';
```

and

```
std::ifstream ist("restrict_words.txt");
    std::string word;
    std::vector<std::string> readWords;
    while(ist >> word)
        readWords.push_back(word);
    //test
    for(unsigned i = 0; i != readWords.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << readWords.at(i) << '\n';
```

Its such a easy thing and im not managing to do this.

I have my KingChatFilter.app and a chat folder inside my game folder. Inside this chat folder i have this txt with 160 words in 160 different lines.

All i need to do is read this txt and after putting it on a array checking if some of this string match with the one i want so i can do other stuff.

Please someone make me understand this thanks :)

[image]

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're having?

Comment: It seems that i am not being able to read the file cause it never enters that while, i putted a breakpoint in the readWords.push_back line and it never hits there...

Comment: @user3120770, You should check that the file stream opened successfully.

Comment: `if (ist)` and `if (ist.is_open())` both work. What you have now is safe if it fails to open, but won't read anything and won't give any error.

Comment: Is your text file in the same directory as your executable?

Comment: Its is not opening successfully :c

Comment: Try to replace "restrict_words.txt" with ".\chat\restrict_words.txt"

Comment: Check if your file is at the right place.

Comment: I tried ("./chat/restrict_words.txt"), (".\chat\restrict_words.txt"), (chat/restrict_words.txt"), ("chat\restrict_words.txt") and just ("restrict_words.txt") my ist var count is always 0

Comment: Try to put the whole path. Check your text file's properties and copy the full address.

Comment: Also try "\chat\restrict_words.txt"

Comment: Changed the fodler name but the .txt is inside that chatTxt folder. ( chekc the picture on the question )

Comment: Did you try with the whole path?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a couple of functions to match your requirements:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>


using namespace std;

// Reads the file line by line and put all lines into words vector.
void read_to_vector(const char* file_name, vector<string> &words) 
{
    ifstream input(file_name);
    string line;

    while (getline(input, line))
    {
        words.push_back(line);
    }
}

// Returns true if word is in words. False otherwise.
bool find_word(vector<string> &words, string word)
{
    vector<string>::iterator it; // In c++11 you can change this to
                                 // auto it;

    // Using std::find from algorithm library.
    it = find(words.begin(), words.end(), word);
    return it != words.end();     // If the end of vector words was reached, then word was NOT found.
}

int main()
{

    vector<string> words;
    string target = "level";

    read_to_vector("data.txt", words);


    if (find_word(words, target))
        cout << "Word " << target << " found" << endl;
    else
        cout << "Word " << target << " not found" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The way you are checking for eof is a bad programming practice.

Comment: @Veritas can you tell me why?

Comment: That's because the eof bit is set only after reaching the end of the file.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Asnwer edited, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

following is working code i used to read file content line by line. One difference is maybe that u do not check if opening the file did succeed. If it does not, there come at least two main reasons to mind:

1. the file cannot be found at the specified path
2. the file is already opened by someone else

;

```
std::string fileNameWithPath = "..\\myFolder\\myfile.txt";
std::ifstream inputFile;
std::vector< std::string > fileContent;

inputFile.open( fileNameWithPath.c_str(), std::ios::in | std::ios::binary );

if( inputFile.is_open() )
{
  std::string line;
  while( std::getline( testDataFile, line ) )
  {
    inputFile.push_back( line );
  }
}

inputFile.close();
```